# Second Person Inanimates in Swahili

Tags: verbs, grammatical-subject

I know what when making verbs about *people* I can use an object placeholder in order to indicate the difference between the first, second and third persons.

So if I'm talking to my daughters I might say..

> nina**ku**penda = I love you
>
> nina**wa**penda **wa**sichana = I love you girls

I'm pretty clear on all that when it comes to people, but what about inanimates or even animates from other noun classes.

What if I'm at the zoo and I'm feeling all sentimental about a rhino and I want to say "I love you rhino" or "I love you rhinos".

Does it work like this..

> nina**ki**penda **ki**faru = I love you Rhino
>
> nina**vi**penda **vi**faru = I love you Rhinos

Or is it simply not possible to address a Rhino in Swahili?

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE!

Answer (score 2):

You can say *ninakupenda(,) Kifaru* "I love you, Rhino", just as you can say *ninakupenda(,) Malaika* "I love you, Malaika". The post-verbal NP is not an argument, and the structure is exactly like "I love you, Lucy". *Ninakipenda kifaru* is kind of dicey, since the agreement should be class 1, since rhinos are animate. However, there is a fair amount of dialect / individual variation on that point. And it would not mean "I love you, Rhino", it would mean "I love a/the rhino". Noun class is indicated only on 3rd person objects. So for example *ninakupenda kibiriti* "I love you, matches".

Answer (score 1):

If you do talk about loving a rhino, it might shift "rhino" into the person noun class.  I don't know any Swahili, but I have a slight acquaintance with another Bantu language, Tumbuka, and I heard a Tumbuka folk tale about animals who have an adventure, much like humans do, and all the class agreement particles are shifted to the person class.

So I'd guess it would depend on whether you're thinking of Rhino as being a person.

Comment: As in most languages equipped with them, category systems are there to be used by speakers, rather than to rule them. Shifting categories is a really good way to economize on vocabulary while marking salient features.

Answer (score 1):

The second person singular object marker is always *-ku-*. The marker *-ki-* is third person and only used for inanimates, which a rhinoceros is not. Addressing something in 2nd person, even something inanimate, requires 2nd person morphology to be used and, in the case of subject or object agreement markers on verbs, that precludes the use of inanimate noun-class markers because they would occupy the same slot.

Animacy is an important topic in Swahili because it is often how semantic differences are clarified in the case of homonyms.

*Kifaru* means not only "rhino" but also "tank", and here, the agreement morphemes make a difference.

*Ninakipenda kifaru.* "I like the tank." (Inanimate. C7 agreement.)
*Ninampenda kifaru.* "I like the rhinoceros." (Animate. C1 agreement.)

Other examples:

*Kiboko alianguka.* "The hippopotamus fell." (Animate. C1 agreement.)
*Kiboko kilianguka.* "The whip fell." (Inanimate. C7 agreement.)

*Ndege waliruka.* "The birds took off." (Animate. C2 agreement.)
*Ndege ziliruka.* "The planes took off." (Inanimate. C10 agreement.)

Answer (score 0):

It would still be "Ni**na**kupenda Kifaru" singular  i.e I love you rhino
                  "Na**wa**penda Vifaru"  plural     i.e I love you rhinos
since Kifaru(rhino) is a living being and hence falls into the same category as humans.

While "ninakipenda kifaru" is wrong in the context that you are portraying, it's more of a third person reference...The correct version, "nina**m**penda kifaru" means I love (a) rhino

PS "nina**ki**penda kifaru" is also correct meaning I love (a) tank(the army kind of tanks that is)